# What causes isNaN to malfunction?

Tags: javascript, nan, numerical-computing

I'm simply trying to evaluate if an input is a number, and figured `isNaN` would be the best way to go. However, this causes unreliable results. For instance, using the following method:

```
function isNumerical(value) {
    var isNum = !isNaN(value);
    return isNum ? "<mark>numerical</mark>" : "not numerical";
}
```

on these values:

```
isNumerical(123));     // => numerical
isNumerical("123"));   // => numerical
isNumerical(null));    // => numerical
isNumerical(false));   // => numerical
isNumerical(true));    // => numerical
isNumerical());        // => not numerical
```

shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4nm7r/1

**Why doesn't `isNaN` always work for me?**

Comment: The logic of your return statement is backwards. Also, things can be non-numerical without being `NaN`.

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks! My question stands, though

Comment: my question is more about what the source of the ambiguity is, rather than how to make my function work

Comment: The ambiguity, I think, is that when coerced to a numeric value (say, by using the unary `+` operator), `+null` becomes 0 but `+undefined` becomes `NaN`. The latter corresponds to your last case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isNaN` returns `true` if the value passed **is not a number(NaN)**(or if it cannot be converted to a number, so, `null`, `true` and `false` will be converted to `0`), otherwise it returns `false`. In your case, you have to remove the `!` before the function call!

It is very easy to understand the behaviour of your script. `isNaN` simply checks if a value can be converted to an int. To do this, you have just to multiply or divide it by 1, or subtract or add 0. In your case, if you do, inside your function, `alert(value * 1);` you will see that all those passed values will be replaced by a number(0, 1, 123) except for `undefined`, whose numerical value is `NaN`.

You can't compare any value to `NaN` because it will never return false(even `NaN === NaN`), I think that's because NaN is dynamically generated... But I'm not sure.

Anyway you can fix your code by simply doing this:

```
function isNumerical(value) {
    var isNum = !isNaN(value / 1); //this will force the conversion to NaN or a number
    return isNum ? "<mark>numerical</mark>" : "not numerical";
}
```

Comment: Good point, and I've modified my post slightly. However, I still would like a reliable way to discover if `value` is numerical

Comment: @Supuhstar Please define "numerical". Should it include true, false, null and undefined? Should strings like "100$" be considered numerical?

Comment: I'm going to use this to parse a cookie. To do this, I need to find out if the stored value was a boolean, number, or text, and I try to avoid string parsing if at all possible

Comment: Try `isNaN(parseFloat(value))` @Supuhstar

Comment: @LightStyle http://jsfiddle.net/4nm7r/3/ your method doesn't work >.>

Comment: @bfavaretto http://jsfiddle.net/4nm7r/4/ works great! Why not submit as an answer?

Comment: I have edited it another(I think the last) time.

Comment: @LightStyle http://jsfiddle.net/4nm7r/5/ still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Supuhstar remove the other `isNaN` function, leave the default one

Comment: @LightStyle http://jsfiddle.net/4nm7r/8/ still has promblembs

Comment: No, it doesn't have problems, it is different from what you expected from it. That's because you wanted something that is not what `isNaN` does, so the code seems not working to you. If you want a different implementation, I think that there are some answers that are exactly what you're looking for. Anyway, mine was just a clarification, because you had not totally clear how `isNaN` works. Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary statement is backward, if `!isNaN()` returns true you want to say `"numerical"`

```
return isNum ? "not numerical" : "<mark>numerical</mark>";
```

should be:

```
return isNum ? "<mark>numerical</mark>" : "not numerical";
```

See updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4nm7r/1/

Answer (score 1):

Now that you already fixed the reversed logic pointed out on other answers, use `parseFloat` to get rid of the false positives for `true`, `false` and `null`:

```
var isNum = !isNaN(parseFloat(value));
```

Just keep in mind the following kinds of outputs from `parseFloat`:

```
parseFloat("200$"); // 200
parseFloat("200,100"); // 200
parseFloat("200 foo"); // 200
parseFloat("$200"); // NaN
```

(i.e, if the string starts with a number, parseFloat will extract the first numeric part it can find)

Comment: This gives me an idea... what if I used regexes? http://jsfiddle.net/4nm7r/7/

Comment: Yep, your regex should work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use additional checks:

```
function isNumerical(value) {
    var isNum = !isNaN(value) && value !== null && value !== undefined;
    return isNum ? "<mark>numerical</mark>" : "not numerical";
}
```

If you would like treat strings like `123` like not numerical than you should add one more check:

```
var isNum = !isNaN(value) && value !== null && value !== undefined && (typeof value === 'number');
```